# Test for convergence of a series using integral test

Tags: integration

I have to test if the following series converges using the integral test:
    $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{x^n+\frac{1}{x^n}}$$
My problem is that I don't know how to do this particular integration. What substitution should I make here?

Thanks,
Raj Mohan

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Do you have any hypothesis on $x$?

Comment: No. Nothing about x is given. I guess we have to consider cases x<1, x=1 and x>1. The case x=1 is easy.

Comment: Yet, to use the integral test, $x$ has to be positive.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

I'll suppose $x>0$. The case $x=1$ diverges trivially, since the general term doesn't tend to $0$.

Rewrite the general term as $\dfrac{x^n}{x^{2n}+1}$. You can use asymptotic equivalence:
$$\dfrac{x^n}{x^{2n}+1}\sim_{n\to\infty}
\begin{cases}x^n&\text{if } 0<x<1, \\ \dfrac{x^n}{x^{2n}}=\dfrac 1{x^n}&\text{if } x>1.
\end{cases}$$
Can you take it from there?

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try to take it up from here.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the integral test
$$I=\int \frac{dn}{x^n+x^{-n}}$$ make $x^n=t$ to get
$$I=\frac 1 {\log(x)}\int \frac {dt}{1+t^2}$$ which is simple. Back to $n$
$$I=\frac{\tan ^{-1}\left(x^n\right)}{\log (x)}$$

Just finish.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. But, I have a question. if $${x^n}=t$$, then won't $$dn=\frac{dt}{t}$$? After duly taking log and then differentiating.

Comment: @RajMohanKovilath. $$x^n=t \implies n=\frac{\log (t)}{\log (x)}\implies dn=\frac{dt}{t \log (x)}$$

Comment: Oops! I forgot the base changing rule. Thanks very much.